Installing standalone software into Client's servers
We have a  new customer boarding us, but since they operate in a remote area, they want our software into their own infrastructure, i.e they will be providing their own servers and the applications needs to connect to that.
We are using azure devops for CI/CD, and i am fairly new to CI/CD as well as this kind of process where we install our asp.net mvc software into the client's server.
The problem is I don't know where to start and what I will be needing in order to get this done.
What I am researching right now is about the build agents in azure devops and how build pipelines work and all. But i dont have any ideas what do i need to do?
What i need is at least a point to the right direction on how can we achieve that in azure devops or Steps of tasks that I need to perform or any docs that provide relevant information?
I am new to Azure devops and I have no clue where to begin.Any help is appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Welcome to DevOps. Here are some general steps you might consider:

Understand Azure DevOps and CI/CD:  Continuous Integration (CI) handles the build and test part of the development cycle, while Continuous Delivery (CD) takes care of deployment. If you don't have the code for deployment yet, you need to prepare it in the build pipeline based on your source code, generate artifact and use it for deployment(release).

Understand and Configure Build Agents: Devops pipeline jobs are running on agent machine. You can use Microsoft-hosted agents, which are managed by Microsoft, or self-hosted agents. As your client works in remote area and has own server, you can simply set their server as self-hosted (link) (or deployment group) agent, so the code will be fetched on the server directly and used for deployment.

Deploy ASP.NET MVC Application: Once your build pipeline is set up and your application is built and tested, the next step is to deploy your application to the client’s server. You can use IIS web app deploy
task for the deployment, please refer to the links below for more details.


Deploy apps to a Windows Virtual Machine
Setting up CI/CD pipeline to deploy a .net core application to an IIS Server through Azure Devops

Thank you so much @wade for your help. I was feeling lost but at least now i have a process. Cheers!
